# PayPal Convert Authorization Transaction to Recurring Payment Profile

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing, payflowpro

I have set up a website that uses the PayPal Payflow API to process payment transactions using a live Payments Pro account that has the Recurring Payment service. It works by first requesting a secure token and then committing the transaction. I have this working using both Hosted Pages (layout c) and Transparent Redirect. I'm using the Payflow_dotNet dll which uses the payflowpro.paypal.com URL.

Now I was told (and discovered) that Recurring payments can't be set up using Secure token so I'm doing this in 2 steps

1. Create an authorization transaction
2. Convert the transaction to a Recurring Payment Profile

So I have step 1 working.  But I have problems with step 2.  Step 2 SAYS that it worked but when I go to PayPal - Profile - My Selling Tools - My Automatic Payments there is nothing there, and the authorization transaction is still listed (as pending) in my History.  Sample code:

```
PayflowNETAPI PayflowNETAPI = new PayflowNETAPI();
string secureTokenID = PayflowUtility.RequestId;
string response = PayflowNETAPI.SubmitTransaction(nvpstring, secureTokenID);
```

Where nvpstring is

```
PARTNER[6]=PayPal&VENDOR[13]=myvendor&USER[6]=Robert&PWD[8]=mypassword&
TRXTYPE=R&ACTION=A&TENDER=C&INVNUM=243&PROFILEREFERENCE=243&PROFILENAME[38]=Mark Groseth--243--Science Center Fund&
START=09182014&TERM=0&PAYPERIOD=MONT&AMT[4]=1.07&ORIGID=ESJPC2894AFC
```

where the ORIGID is the PNREF that was returned when creating the authorization transaction.
This even gives me a resulting RPREF and ProfileID like RP0000000005.  So where did it go? why didn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you use the Payflow API all the recurring profiles will be stored at manager.paypal.com. In other words, all the recurring profiles starting with RP... will be there in the manager account. Once you login to the manager account, go to "Service Settings", then "Manage Profiles". Here you will see the recurring profile.

Comment: THANKS, so it appears that my code has been working for several days now.  I tried googling the location of the profile manager several times.  it should be easier, it should be documented.

Comment: Why do the source Authorization transactions still appear in my History if they have been successfully converted?  Is that just how it works?  Is there a way to delete those Authorization transactions?

Comment: Also, when converting an Authorization that was done with a PayPal account then the Recurring payment has no account number and payments fails with Result 7 - field format error

Comment: Creating the recurring profiles for the PayPal Payments works differently . You need to set up the Billing agreement with the buyer and then you will use that Billing agreement ID to create the recurring profile . You can refer the below document for more information . Check the page no 16 for PayPal Payments : https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf

Comment: I am intimately familiar with that guide.  But it does not explain how to create a RP when using Payflow to pay with a paypal account.  I'm not aware of any way to get an BAID using payflow.  PayPal rules require that I provide users the option to pay with a paypal account.  Probably I should start a new question for this